# Overriding clean() method of Parent django form in child/inherited form

Tags: django

I am really having a hard time figuring this out. The bottom problem is that I need to somehow either set initial value for password field or override the way the method validate_member is called.

I have this form, which is called when a member needs to register to the system directly:

```
class NewMemberForm(forms.Form):
    '''
    Called when user wants to register with our system from web/mobile. Ask password here

    '''

    firstName=forms.CharField(max_length=25,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput())
    lastName=forms.CharField(max_length=25,required=True,widget=forms.TextInput())
    birthdate=forms.DateField(required=True)
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(choices=Profile.GENDER,required=True)
    idnumber=forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=25)
    phone=forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=16,widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    memberType=forms.ChoiceField(choices=Profile.TYPE_OF_MEMBER,widget=forms.Select())
    maritalStatus=forms.ChoiceField(choices=Profile.MARITAL_STATUS,widget=forms.Select())



    def clean(self):
        '''
        Grouped cleaning
        '''
        self.cleaned_data=super(NewMemberForm,self).clean()

        validate_member_form=validate_member(self.cleaned_data,False)

        #do we have error messages now?

        if len(validate_member_form[0])>0: #yes we have error messages
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(validate_member_form[0]),code='invalid')

        return validate_member_form[1]
```

the validate_member function is used during editing and adding information, thus cleaned the clean() to keep things DRY. Now, I have another scenario in which a member could be registered by another member (with some rights). In that case, the password and membertype fields are not needed with one new field added to the form named role; so I decided to inherit the form:

```
class MemberAddForm(NewMemberForm):

    #memberType=forms.CharField(initial='Individual',required=False,widget=forms.Select()) #iignored: here to simple override the Required declaraton in memberform
    #password=forms.CharField(max_length=16,widget=forms.PasswordInput(),required=False,initial='111111') #note pwd is ignored during saving and a new is generated
    role=forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),required=True,queryset=Activity.objects.filter(active='Active').only('id','name'),empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MemberAddForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].initial='123456' #note this is meangingless and in place to pass validate_member
        self.fields['password'].required=False
        self.fields['memberType'].initial='Individual'
        self.fields['memberType'].required=False

    def clean(self):
        '''
        This is not been used at all.
        '''

        self.cleaned_data=super(MemberAddForm,self).clean()
        self.cleaned_data['password']='!983.kIl'


        #validate_member_form=validate_member(self.cleaned_data,False,False)

        #do we have error messages now?

        if len(validate_member_form[0])>0: #yes we have error messages
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(validate_member_form[0]),code='invalid')
```

Now, I noticed the clean() method in the child class is ignored entirely and validation is being taken care of from parent.clean() only. I would really need to pass the third parameter as False in the validate_member method (it is True in the Parent class). The validate_member checks password complexity and stuff. Setting the required=False helps partly because 'this field is required' error is no more shown; however, the password is still checked complexity. As you can see, I set the password to initial value that passes password setting but still I get error no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

This line in child class is causing that parent's `clean` method is called:

```
self.cleaned_data=super(MemberAddForm,self).clean()
```

As the two are almost the same, it looks like the child's one is not called, i.e. if parent's `clean` passes successfully also the child's one will.

Solution for your problem would be to modify the paren's `clean` method to:

```
   def clean(self, validate_member=True):
        '''
        Grouped cleaning
        '''
        self.cleaned_data=super(NewMemberForm,self).clean()

        if validate_member:
            validate_member_form=validate_member(self.cleaned_data, False)

        # Do we have error messages now?
        if len(validate_member_form[0]) > 0:  # yes we have error messages
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(validate_member_form[0]), code='invalid')

        return validate_member_form[1]
```

And then all you have to do in child's `clean` method is:

```
def clean(self):
    return super(NewMemberForm,self).clean(validate_member=False)
```

Comment: Sorry i wrongly marked your comment as an answer. But i am not sure if clean() method accepts arguements? Or was it full clean that doesn't. Let me try please.

Comment: It is ok to define extra arguments (i.e. in parents `clean` functions), just make sure to set default values, so they can be called in a standard Django way.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option

```
# dynamic form creation
class CreateUpdateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'apps/frontend/create_update_view.j2'
    def get_form_class(self):
        # url like: /user/(?P<mode>[^/]+)/ - /user/register/ or /user/update/
        is_password_required = self.kwargs.get('mode') == 'register'

        class _Form(forms.Form):
            if is_password_required:
                password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

            first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25, required=True)

        return _Form
```

Comment: It does work but i think the solution of Domen is easier to merge into my currently running app. Thanks Vadimchin for the alternative solution which i didnt think of at all.